# Assertion failure: list iterator not incrementable (not in a loop)

Tags: c++, list, iterator, erase, assertion

First off, good morning/day/evening and thank you to whoever is taking their time to read this.

**The Setup:**

In my code I have two different classes: ColObj and QuadNode (that is, the 'collision object' and a node in a quad tree used to check for proximity of objects. I know there are probably libraries out there for this, but I need to write my own system, so they would be of no use here). Things work like this: When a ColObj object is created, it is added into an appropriate QuadNode (the node has a std::list of pointers to ColObj), so that the node can inform it when it collides with something; the ColObj object also receives a pointer to the node that's holding it and a list iterator to the list iterator containing its address so when it's out of the node's bounds or gets destroyed it can 'leave' it, and clean up the node, that is, remove and reference to itself from the node. I made it like this because in a lot of cases it's going to be a frequent operation and I want it to be in constant time.

**The Code:**

This is the method used to 'attach' a ColObj to a QuadNode. I suspect the problem is not in here.

```
void QuadNode::obj_add(ColObj *obj) {

    std::cout<<"QuadNode at depth ("<<depth<<") received new ColObj.\n";

    objects.push_back(obj);

    obj->holder  = this;
    obj->my_iter = std::prev( objects.end() );

    if ((int)objects.size() > MAX_OBJECTS && depth < MAX_DEPTH) split();

    }
```

This is the QuadNode method that a ColObj uses to clean up the node. Here is where the problem occures for some reason.

```
void QuadNode::obj_list_erase(std::list<ColObj*>::iterator iter) {

    std::list<ColObj*>::iterator iter2 = objects.begin();

    objects.erase(iter);

    }
```

The first line in this method is simply to provide additional information for debugging and will be removed afterwards.

**The Error:**

The strangest part is that, for the most part, the code works fine. Then at one point, randomly, it throws an assertion failure, saying that a "list iterator is not incrementable". That's the first strange thing, I'm not trying to increment it anywhere in my code (though I know that std::list::erase returns the following iterator, but I never attempt this operation on an invalid or "past-the-last" iterator).

Anyway, Visual Studio offers to fire up the debugger and put a break point in the code, so naturally I agree. So here's the weirdest part:

[Local and auto variables, debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnMHY.png)

(I can't embed an image since I'm new here, so it is what it is).

So, unless I'm gravely mistaken here, it's telling me that the passed iterator is equal to be beginning iterator of the list, that its element is still present in the list and corresponds to the first (or rather zero-th) element of the list. And yet, the erase() method fails.
For what it's worth, I've noticed that every single time the program breaks, the passed iterator points to the zero-th element of the list, though I can confirm that the method usually works even when there's only one element in the list.

**Additional info and conclusion:**

I'm not manually incrementing the iterator anywhere else in the code (which is pretty small and simple anyway).

The IDE I'm using is Visual Studio Community 2015, but I don't know the compiler version. (Microsoft and their naming schemes...)

I tried finding another thread about this on SO but every one I checked was about wrongly placed i++ in list iterations, so sorry if this is a duplicate thread.

I'm completely confused by this problem, because usually between the excellent debugger, std::cout and browsing SO I somehow fix the issue, but this time around nothing useful is coming up, so any advice or suggestion would be very welcome.

**Edit:**

One thing I have tried "just 'cause" editing the QuadNode::obj_list_erase method so that it compares the passed iterator with the first iterator of its list (objects.begin()) and if they're equal use objects.pop() to remove it, else erase it normally. It didn't work, saying that the iterators weren't compatible, whatever that means...

Comment: Here's an excellent "advice or suggestion": TL;DR. Reduce your code to a [mcve], that anyone can use to reproduce your problem, then replace everything you've written, above, with your [mcve]. All the debugger does is show you the state of your program when it crashed. The state of your program when it crashed is utterly irrelevant. You need to know ***why*** it reached that state. Unless it's obvious, from the post-mortem, speculation is a waste of time.

Comment: *"I don't know the compiler version. (Microsoft and their naming schemes...)"* - Open a developer command prompt and type `cl.exe /?`. That will display the compiler version, no matter what naming scheme Microsoft have opted to use. (What's wrong with it anyway?) Besides, the assertion dialog doens't offer to set a breakpoint. It offers to take you right to the debug assertion that failed. Do it. The callstack will be revealing.

Comment: @IInspectable Okay so I checked the compiler version, and it's: 19.00.24215.1, Optimizing Compiler for x86 (Thank you for the tip, I didn't know you could do it like that.). I checked the call stack after the assertion again (I have checked it before) but it shows only the expected call chain, and then [External Code], and I'm guessing that's not what you were aiming at. Anyway, I'll do as Sam Varshavchick suggested and construct a minimal example.

Comment: 1)in QuadNode::obj_list_erase you remove pointer from list, but do not delete object (possible memory leak);
2) it is my speculation (on base of snippet you provided) : split() splits list, and so invalidate iterators, stored in ColObj objects, then you pass invalidated iterator from one of your ColObj objects in QuadNode::obj_list_erase and strange thing happens (ub)

Comment: A QuadNode does not own ColObj objects, so it is not its responsibility to delete them, only "keep them informed" until references to them are removed from said node. And split() at some point calls obj_add() which in turn updates the object's holder info.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur After further investigation... You were almost completely right. Turns out there was a possible situation where the object list would get reordered, thus invalidating the iterators (as you said), but without updating the ColObj's holder info... If it were an answer I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

After finding out that I cannot even compare the passed iterator with any other iterator from the list that was supposed to be holding it (I was getting Assertion failure: iterators not compatible), I searched SO for more info on what it means, and... Andrew Kashpur was right. I did manage to invalidate an iterator by removing the pointed element from the list and putting it back immediately, but without updating the iterator.

Moral of the story: An iterator can seem to point to a "correct" memory location, it may even point to the same address as some valid iterator does, but that does not make it valid or compatible.